# Requesting help in reading blob datatype in mariadb via python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mariadb, blob

I am trying to print the content inside blob data type and here is my python code and as well the error.

What is the best method to read blob data via python?

Any help here is really appreciated.

Link to the table screenshot.

[image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEymN.png)

I got to know the blob data type column contains floating point numbers, given sample below.

6.213203675953e-311
1.69759663307e-313
3e-323
1.697596633e-313
2.121995969e-314
5e-324
6.1113478779844e-311
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
4.473620042652186
.
.
.
.

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

db_config = {
    'host': '123.0.0.0',
    'port': '1000',
    'database': 'any_db',
    'user': 'user_name',
    'password': 'pass_word'
    }


def read_blob(cell, experiment):
sql = """select Tuning_Curve_AuC from Cell_Table where cell = %s and experiment = %s"""

try:
    # query blob data form the authors table
    conn = mariadb.connect(**db_config)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, (cell, experiment))
    blob = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(blob)

except(Exception, mariadb.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)

finally:
    if conn is not None:
       conn.close()
       print('Database connection closed.')

def main():
read_blob(1, 'E40_062716')

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Error:

```
<built-in method fetch_row of _mysql_connector.MySQL object at 0x7ff57f2b5e00> returned a result with an error set
```

Database connection closed.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and got the solution. It turns out that we have to fetch raw data and use array to convert it to decimals(floating). Here's that part of the code snippet.

```
    conn = mariadb.connect(**db_config)
    cursor = conn.cursor(raw=True)
    cursor.execute(sql, (cell, experiment))
    blob = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    doubles_sequence = array.array('d', blob)
    print(doubles_sequence)
```

and of course,  you have to 'import array'.